# Is the well in the market functional?

Tags: banished

The market structure in Banished features a well in the middle of the building. It looks exactly the same as the well structure that can be constructed to help with firefighting in areas of the town that are far from natural sources of water, but does it work in the same manner?

Answer (score 6):

**No.**

It is purely cosmetic and does not serve as a source of water during a fire.
[Source](http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Market)